# Librosa : MFCC feature calculation

Tags: python, audio, audio-processing, mfcc

Given a audio file of `22 mins (1320 secs)`, Librosa extracts a MFCC features by 
`data = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=None, sr=22050, S=None, n_mfcc=20, **kwargs)`

> > data.shape
> >     (20,56829)
> >     It returns numpy array of 20 MFCC features of 56829 frames .

My question is how it calculated 56829. Is there any calculation to achieve this frame ? and What is the window size for each frame ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can specify the hop length

```
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length, n_mfcc=13)
```

librosa uses centered frames, so that the kth frame is centered around sample k * hop_length

I think that default hop value is 512, with your data (1320*22050)/56829 = 512,16